# WordPress get_posts problem; adding category argument seemingly nullifies numberposts

Tags: wordpress

I have two different get_posts functions as follows:

```
<!-- Begin Left Middle -->
    <div id="leftmiddle">
        <h1><a href="/category/recent-cases">Recent Cases</a></h1>
        <?php
            global $post;
            $postslist = get_posts('category=5&numberposts=2');
            foreach ($postslist as $post) : 
                setup_postdata($post);
        ?> 
            <div id="latest_post">
                <span class="theme date"><?php the_date(); ?></span>
                <br />
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>       
    </div>
<!-- End Left Middle -->

<!-- Begin Right Middle -->
    <div id="rightmiddle">
        <h1><a href="/blog">Latest Posts</a></h1>
        <?php
            $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=2&order=DESC&orderby=date&category=-5');
            foreach ($postslist as $post) : 
                setup_postdata($post);
        ?> 
            <div id="latest_post">
                <span class="theme date"><?php the_date(); ?></span>
                <br />
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
<!-- End Right Middle -->
```

Now in **rightmiddle** it does everything as expected; lists only the two most recent posts that aren't in category 5. However, in **leftmiddle** it lists all the posts in category 5. If I remove the category argument in **leftmiddle** or I change it to a negating param like in **rightmiddle**, numberposts works as expected. Why is that?

Comment: You should repost the question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. This is more of a customization than a programming problem, and the experts are over there.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a two different variable names to hold the return values from your calls to `get_posts()`.  Right now you are using the same variable name `$postslist`.  They might be interfering, which is why the last call in **rightmiddle** works.

You are also declaring `global $post` in leftmiddle but not rightmiddle.